# MySQL performance differences between a different "FROM" operator usage

Tags: mysql, sql, database, performance, database-schema

Can someone please explain to me why this:

```
SELECT 
    A.id,
    A.name,
    B.id AS title_id
FROM title_information AS A
JOIN titles B ON B.title_id = A.id
WHERE
    A.name LIKE '%testing%'
```

is considerably slower (6-7 times) than this:

```
SELECT 
    A.id,
    A.name,
    B.id AS title_id
FROM (SELECT id, name FROM title_information) AS A
JOIN titles B ON B.title_id = A.id
WHERE
    A.name LIKE '%testing%'
```

I know it's probably hard to answer this question without knowing full details about the schema and MySQL configuration, but I'm looking for any generic reasons why the first example could be so significantly slower than the second?

Running EXPLAIN gives this:

```
|| *id* || *select_type* || *table*  || *type*  || *possible_keys*           || *key*   || *key_len* || *ref*             || *rows* || *Extra*     ||
|| 1    || SIMPLE        || B        || index   ||                           || id      || 12        ||                   || 80407  || Using index ||
|| 1    || SIMPLE        || A        || eq_ref  || PRIMARY,id_UNIQUE,Index 4 || PRIMARY || 4         || newsql.B.title_id || 1      || Using where ||
```

and

```
|| *id* || *select_type* || *table*           || *type* || *possible_keys* || *key*   || *key_len* || *ref* || *rows* || *Extra*                         ||
|| 1    || PRIMARY       || B                 || index  ||                 || id      || 12        ||       || 80407  || Using index                     ||
|| 1    || PRIMARY       || <derived2>        || ALL    ||                 ||         ||           ||       || 71038  || Using where; Using join buffer  ||
|| 2    || DERIVED       || title_information || index  ||                 || Index 4 || 206       ||       || 71038  || Using index                     ||
```

**UPDATE:**
A.id and B.id are both PRIMARY KEYS, while A.name is an index. Both tables have around 50,000 rows (~15MB). MySQL configuration is pretty much a default one.

Not sure if that helps (or if it adds more to the confusion - as it does for me) but using more generic LIKE statement that is likely to have more matching fields (e.g. *"LIKE '%x%'"*) makes the first query run considerably faster. On the other hand, using *"LIKE '%there are no records matching this%'"* will make the second query a lot faster (while the first one struggles).

Anyone can shed some light on what's going on here?

Thank you!

Comment: Are you selecting the same number of rows? I would expect that the first may be quicker over the first 20 rows of query, say, but the optimizer _should_ treat them both similarly if you're getting everything. What are your indexes?

Comment: @Ben all selected fields are indexed. Actually A.id and B.id are both UNIQUE PRIMARY KEYs, while A.name is a simple index. And yes, I would also assume that the first one would be either the same or faster than the second one. But it's not what I'm seeing, which brings all of this confusion. In my table execution times are ~3s vs ~0.5s accordingly.

Comment: What engine are the tables using? What is the version of MySQL?

Answer (score 0):

This is speculation (my powers of reading MySQL explain output are weaker than they should be, because I want to see data flow diagrams).

But here is what I think is happening.  The first query is saying "Let's go through B and look up the appropriate value in A".  It then looks up the appropriate value using the `id` index, then it needs to fetch the page and compare to `name`.  These accesses are inefficient, because they are not sequential.

The second version appears to recognize the condition on `name` as being important.  It is going through the `name` index on A and only fetching the matching rows as needed.  This is faster, because the data is in the index and few pages are needed for the matching names.  The match to B is then pretty simple, with only one row to match.

I am surprised at the performance difference.  Usually, derived tables are bad performance-wise, but this is clearly an exception.